# Change image with transition with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create imgs that change on click but I don't know how to create a fade in / fade out effect to toggle the images. I need a "before" and "post production" box to show to users how my costumer works with photos. I'm using bootstrap for this project

I tried this and I also tried to add and remove classes to have an effect but I still can't have the effect

```js
function swap(t) {
  if (t.src != t.getAttribute('data-secondImg')) {
    t.old = t.src;
    t.src = t.getAttribute('data-secondImg');

  } else {
    t.src = t.old;
  }
}
```

```css
.post-production-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.post-production-container .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  transition: 2s all;
}

.post-production-container .box .imgBx {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.post-production-container .box .imgBx img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  pointer-events: all;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 2s;
}

.post-production-container .box .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post-production-container .box .content h2 {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: translateY(200px);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.post-production-container .box:hover .content h2 {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.post-production-container .box .content p {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(200px);
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.post-production-container .box:hover .content p {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .post-production-container:hover .box {
    transform: rotateY(25deg);
  }
  .post-production-container .box:hover~.box {
    transform: rotateY(-25deg);
  }
  .post-production-container .box:hover {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.25);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 25px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="post-production-container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx col">
        <img src="./assets/img/prima-dopo/ferrero-prima.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" data-secondImg="./assets/img/prima-dopo/ferrero-dopo.jpg">

      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <h2>Image Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi accusamus molestias quidem iusto.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx col">
        <img src="./assets/img/prima-dopo/coppette-prima.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" onMouseOver="swap(this)" data-secondImg="./assets/img/prima-dopo/coppette-dopo.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <h2>Image Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi accusamus molestias quidem iusto.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: Are you deliberately binding the same function to *both* the `onClick` and `onMouseover`? May I ask what the design goal is?

Comment: He ask me to create an effect like the "before - after" slider here "https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/DJqNKP" but on click and I can't have a transition on click while the image change. Then I have to create the same effect for mobile on scroll when in the viewport. For now I am working on click and transition problem

Comment: the second one on mouse over is an error, only by click